# Having an issue with using Tenda Wireless PCI Adapter W322p setup

Tags: wireless, networking

I am still a beginner with installing and configuring with Linux. I would just like to know what I can do to get the Tenda adapter to function and recognize wireless networks. Please let me know of any screenshots that are needed and/or more info.

I have the disk that has come with the product as well.

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you,

Comment: Please edit your question to add details of your wireless card from the terminal command: lspci -nn | grep 0280

Comment: 03:01.0 Network Controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:3062]

Answer (score 0):

In all recent Ubuntu  versions, your device is covered by the driver rt2800pci that's built-in already. Please open a terminal and check to see if it's loaded:

```
lsmod | grep rt2
```

If not, load it:

```
sudo modprobe rt2800pci
```

Was a wireless interface created, ideally wlan0?

```
iwconfig
```

Does it scan and see networks?

```
sudo iwlist wlan0 scan
```

Are there any informative clues in the logs?

```
dmesg | grep -e wlan -e rt2
```

Finally, what Ubuntu version are you running?

```
lsb_release -d
```

Comment: The driver rt2800pci was in the list. I then followed the instructions on modprobe, but I do not think that anything changed. With "iwconfig" this was the result.

lo - no wireless ext.

eth0 - no wireless ext.

wlan0 - IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:off/any
Mode:Managed Access Point: Not-Associated Tx-Power=20 dBm
Retry long limit:7 RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
Power Management:off

Comment: Also unsuccessful in the scanning process. "wlan0 - No scan results"

Logs had not shown anything useful 

I am using Natty Narwhal now. 11.04 Kern: 2.6.38-11

Comment: Ubuntu 11.04 reached end of life on October 28, 2012. You will no longer receive crucial security updates. I suggest you upgrade to 12.04 LTS at the least.